# DTFT of this signal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-transform

How can I calculate the DTFT of the following signal with properties? I suspect I would obtain a pulse, but I can not figure out how to calculate it.

$x[n]$ for n=0,1...,9.

$$x[n]=\frac {\sin (\frac{3\pi n}{10})} {\sin (\frac{\pi n}{10})}$$
Elsewhere $$x[n]=0$$

A step-by-step solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula), you can establish the [Dirichlet kernel formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel):
For any $x\in\mathbb R$ and $p\in\mathbb N$, $$\frac{\sin\left(\left(p+\frac 1 2\right)x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac x 2\right)}=\sum_{k=-p}^p e^{ikx}$$
So applying this with $p=1$ and $x=\frac {\pi n} 5$
$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi n}{10}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac {\pi n}{10}\right)}=\sum_{k=-1}^1 e^{ik\frac{\pi n}5} = 1 + e^{-in\frac{\pi}5} + e^{in\frac{\pi}5}$$

Now applying the formula for the DTFT:
$$\begin{split}
X(\omega) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}x[n]e^{-i\omega n}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^9e^{-i\omega n}\right) + \left(\sum_{n=0}^9e^{-i n(\frac {\pi}{5} +\omega)}\right) +\left(\sum_{n=0}^9e^{i n(\frac {\pi}{5} -\omega)}\right)
\end{split}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you, it is really helpful. Yes, I can finish from this point.

Comment: You're welcome!